# Lyapunov exponents as a measure of chaos and how to report them

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory

How are Lyapunov exponents of dynamical systems used as a measure of chaos? If I have the double pendulum, a chaotic system, then using the equation for the [Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent#Definition_of_the_maximal_Lyapunov_exponent) (Wikipedia's article "Lyapunov exponent" viewed on 25/03/24):
$$\lambda =\lim _{t\to \infty }\lim _{|\delta \mathbf {Z} _{0}|\to 0}{\frac {1}{t}}\ln {\frac {|\delta \mathbf {Z} (t)|}{|\delta \mathbf {Z} _{0}|}}$$
Then in phase space since $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $p_1$, and $p_2$ are all bounded, $\delta\mathbf{Z}(t)$ is bounded, so the $1/t$ should be dominant and the exponent goes to zero. Does a non-zero exponent occur depending on the path that we take the limit $\left(t,\delta\mathbf{Z}_0\right)\rightarrow\left(\infty,0\right)$?

Further, how is the maximal Lyapunov exponent useful for reporting chaos (i.e., as in research papers)? If we instead had a double spherical pendulum, then $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$, $p_{\theta_1}$, $p_{\theta_2}$, $p_{\varphi_1}$, and $p_{\varphi_2}$ all give infinitesimal separation, so in general:

$$\delta \mathbf{Z}_0=\delta\theta_1\,\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_1+\delta\theta_2\,\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_2+\delta\varphi_1\,\boldsymbol{\hat{\varphi}}_1+\delta\varphi_2\,\boldsymbol{\hat{\varphi}}_2+\delta p_{\theta_1}\,\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}_{\theta_1}+\delta p_{\theta_2}\,\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}_{\theta_2}+\delta p_{\varphi_1}\,\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}_{\varphi}+\delta p_{\varphi_2}\,\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}_{\varphi_2}$$

So shouldn't $\lambda$ in general depend on $\delta\theta_1$, $\delta\theta_2$, $\delta\varphi_1$, $\delta\varphi_2$, $\delta p_{\theta_1}$, $\delta p_{\theta_2}$, $\delta p_{\varphi_1}$, and $\delta p_{\varphi_2}$ giving it 8 degrees of freedom? Or is the *maximal* Lyapunov exponent also defined as the *maximum* value of this as we approach zero phase space separation, which allows us to report a single $\lambda$ for each point in phase space (which is still an 8-dimensional quantity, so I find it hard to see how this could be shown in a meaningful way)? Even for a double pendulum, you can't show a 4-dimensional density plot of the magnitude of the Lyapunov exponent making it seem quite difficult to show in any dimension larger than 1D.

Comment: Note that the limit is double: $t\rightarrow \infty$ but $\delta Z_0\rightarrow 0$, so the result will typically be finite and nonzero. However, this limit is unsuitable for actually measuring the exponents, other numerical methods work far better. Second, the exponents are averaged over the attractor rather than measured at particular points. Hence for a N-dimentsional attractor you only get N exponents.